# Удалить каждый n-вы элемент из array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть массив:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Нужно удалить элемент на каждой 6-й итерации, пока в массиве не останется одно число.
То есть удалится сначала 1, потом 3, потом 5.
Как это сделать на JavaScript?

Comment: Какое-то непонятное задание. "Нужно удалить каждое 6-е число, но при этом удаляются 1,3,5"

Comment: 1 - 1, 2 - 2, 3 - 3, 4 - 4, 5 - 5, числа закончились, а счёт продолжается с начала 1 - 6 и его и удаляем, так как оно шестое

Comment: так Вы хотите удалить не КАЖДОЕ 6-е число, а удалить число на каждой 6-й итерации. Тогда задача должна включать еще 1 условие: кол-во итераций

Comment: Пока не останется последнее число

Answer (score 3):

Текст вопроса можно интерпретировать двояко:

1) после удаления элемента счет должен заново начинаться с первого элемента массива;

2) после удаления элемента счет должен продолжаться с того же места (по принципу детской считалочки).

Соответственно, вот оба варианта:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const N = 6;

// после удаления элемента счет начинается с начала массива
function countOut1(arr, n) {
  arr = [].concat(arr); // чтобы функция не имела побочных эффектов, создается копия исходного массива
  while (arr.length > 1) {
    let pos = (n - 1) % arr.length;
    arr.splice(pos, 1);
  }
  return arr[0];
}

// после удаления элемента счет продолжается с того же места
function countOut2(arr, n) {
  arr = [].concat(arr); // чтобы функция не имела побочных эффектов, создается копия исходного массива
  let pos = 0;
  while (arr.length > 1) {
    pos = (pos + n - 1) % arr.length;
    arr.splice(pos, 1);
  }
  return arr[0];
}

console.log(countOut1(arr, N));
console.log(countOut2(arr, N));
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно как-то так:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  index = 0,
  recursive = function(array) {
    let i = 0,
      length = array.length;
    if (index > length) {
      return array.filter(val => null !== val);
    }
    if (!length) {
      return;
    }
    while (true) {
      if (6 === i) {
        i = 0;
        if (!index || index) {
          delete arr[index];
        }
        index += 2;
        return recursive(array);
      }
      ++i;
    }
  };
arr = recursive(arr);
console.log(arr);
```